# What does Apple use to consider my app "new" or "updated

Tags: ios, app-store

I just got the following from Apple:

[image]

We have got this message many times before. New apps have to have this completed by April 2020, Updated Apps by December 2020.

To us this is an updated App. It has been in Test Flight for over a year and we updated date it about every month. We use a different a unique app bundle for promotion to the App Store. I don't know why.

The only thing I can see that we did differently was we needed a new provisioning profile. But that shouldn't mean it is a "new" app.

What criteria does Apple use to indicate whether an app is "new" or "updated".

Comment: Apple checks the bundle id of the uploaded build. If a bundle id has been previously published to the the store then it is an update. If that bundle id has never been published then it is a new app.  You say you are using a different bundle id for publishing to the store, so if this is the first time you have used that bundle id then it is a new app.  But seriously, you have been receiving these warnings for months and ignoring them?  Why not just fix it ages ago

Answer (score 0):

These information are send on a "per build"-basis. Once Apple receives a build and processes it, you will get these "informational" emails. It does not really matter, when you build the app, made any changes or similar. The "deprecated" emails only get important if you plan on submitting the build for review.

Comment: Max, we just want to update an app we have been using in TestFlight for 18 months for testing. We have received these warnings for a long time, as Apple is good about warning us. This is an update to an existing app, not a new app, yet Apple indicates it is new. Did they just make a mistake?

Comment: Apps cannot use UIWebView anymore. So any updates to existing apps most follow those rules. Simply check out https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12232019b that contains all the information.

Comment: I did read that. Did you miss this part?  The App Store will no longer accept new apps using UIWebView as of April 2020 and app updates using UIWebView as of December 2020. We are UPDATING our app, it is not new.

Comment: Did you read this part: "...and app updates using UIWebView as of December 2020" After December 2020 you can no longer longer push updates to apps including UIWebView. There is no "updating a new app", either it's new or it's an update.

Comment: As I said, it is not a new app, it is an update to an app. I checked in Apple's Forums and other people are complaining about this very same thing. I am pretty sure Apple has made a mistake.